# How to create floating notification / Head-up with react native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, notifications, expo

i was created local notification without other third party, My expectation is that notifications are like whatsapp message floating and there are actions button,success show notification but not floating/popup notification

[image: floating notification]

```
Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('location-reached', {
    name: 'location-reached',
    importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
    vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
    lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
});

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
    handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: true,
        shouldPlaySound: true,
        shouldSetBadge: true,
        priority: "high",

    }),
});

export const sendNotification = async (address) => {

    const id = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync( {
        content: {
            title: `Destination will arrive soon`,
            body: address,
            sound: 'default',
            vibrate: true,
        },
        trigger: {
            seconds: 1,
            channelId: 'location-reached'
        },
    });
    console.log("notif id on scheduling", id)
    return id;
}
```

i was give permission for this notif
[image]

Comment: Bult-in Expo Notification package has limited notification features and customization. You need to add third-party libraries like Notifee -https://notifee.app/

Comment: I think it can, but i don't know how to apply it

Comment: Notifee depends on native modules which not compatible with Expo Go client. It required to compile Expo Custom Dev with  Notifee pre-embeded